# Call Vue 3 function by it's name in string variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-sfc

In my script setup SFC I want to dynamically call another function from the same component by it's name in string variable, right now I'm doing it that way:

```
let functionName = "myFunction(param)";
eval(functionName);
```

I read on MDN docs that using eval is dangerous, I tried to use return Function but it gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined" or "TypeError: [...] is not a function"

is there a better way or do I have to use eval?

Comment: This is XY problem. Consider explaining the problem in details instead of focusing on a wrong way to solve it. Eval is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function as property inside a literal object then call it using brackets:

```js
const funcs={
  myFunction:function(param){
   ///
  }
}

// and now you could call it like 
funcs["myFunction"](yourArg)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done here is assigned a string to the variable `functionName`. Though your post lacks some context, if you are just trying to call one function from another, it would look like this:

```
<script setup>

function myFunction(params){};
function myOtherFunction(){
   myFunction()
};

</script>
```

Or more like how you have it written. This is valid syntax as well:

```
let myFunction = (params) => {};
let myOtherFunction = (params) => {
  myFunction(params);
}
```